# Allow scheduling pod when we have anti affinity enabled

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-on-premises

I have a deployment where I have added affinity as below -

```
affinity:
  nodeAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - example.com
  podAntiAffinity:
    requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    - labelSelector:
        matchExpressions:
        - key: component
          operator: In
          values:
          - myapp
      topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

Now, whenever I update configurations in this pod, Upgraded pod is not being scheduled due to error -

> Warning  FailedScheduling  12s   default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match pod anti-affinity rules. preemption:
> 0/1 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming
> pod

Please provide suggestions, how can I fix this issue.